# How to make a row stick

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a list (key->value) and don't want the values falling beneath the items when resizing the window. I tried to use "row" but values go beneath the item when window is resized.

What can I use to make the row stick?

[image]

Comment: Might want to take a look at `row-fluid` instead of `row`.

Comment: and what do you want? ScrollX or liquid layout?

Comment: @robbrit Take a look at this: http://i.imgur.com/xeB2W.png - the first row is with `row-fluid` and the second row is with `row`
@chumkiu This is not what I want (take a look at the image above). I want this to stick how matter small I resize the window: Key: Value

Comment: You'll have to put all the rows as either `row` or `row-fluid`, mixing them doesn't work too well. The difference between the two is that `row` is fixed-width at 940px, if you go smaller than that it will wrap. `row-fluid` will dynamically adjust to the size of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a responsive layout you should use `row-fluid` in a `container-fluid`. ([see doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts))

But personally for this case I would use the `<table>`, because it sounds like a tabular data. (however I don't know your specific case and I may be wrong)

Comment: Because this is tabular data, I've decided just to use `<table>`